# Web.Config Transform not working in Visual Studio 22

Tags: visual-studio, webforms, web-config, transformation

I am trying to get Web.config transformation working in VS 2022 withing a WebForms application. The goal is to enable transformation on BUILD.

I have followed this guide (among others): https://gist.github.com/EdCharbeneau/9135216

My .csproj looks like this:

```
 <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <TransformXml Source="Web.Base.config" Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" Destination="Web.config" />
  </Target>
```

This since to be okay since no error is displayed (saying that it can't find the path for example). $(VisualStudioVersion) therefore correctly resolves to "17.0".

The files in the solution explorer are present:

[image]

Web.config is (almost) empty and Web.Base.config contains the actual config.

Problem: When I build my project, Web.config is not overwritten and the application ends up without configuration. I have read multiple guides and questions on this topic, but I can't find anything wrong with my setup.

Does anyone have a clue why the transformation from Web.base.config to Web.config doesn't work?

Comment: transforms only work on publish - not a build. So, you can still test your site local, as debug, or release - you still be using the web config. the transforms will only kick into action when you use the build->publish options.

Comment: And as I have stated, the goal here is to transform on BUILD. That's why I linked a guide that describes this. It definetely is possible by hooking onto BeforeBuild or AfterBuild. It just doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following code in a few projects and it seems to still workin Visual Studio 2022. I have a Web.Base.config (and configuration) and I set the default values in there. I then add a configuration and a Web.{ConfigurationName}.config for each environment.  During Build and Publish, it overwrites the Web.config file with what was selected in the configuration.

```
<UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
<Target Name="Web_config_AfterBuild" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="Exists('Web.$(Configuration).config')">
<TransformXml Source="Web.config" Destination="$(OutputPath)Web.config" Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" />
```

I have several imports, but not sure which one is for that.

Comment: This is the right way to do it... You can apply all the transformations at the publish stage by default, but this option lets you do it at the build stage. This is useful for some build pipelines. 
I use this technique to configure CM and CD environments in Sitecore build pipeline. Then I move them to a release pipeline. So I can do ANY transformations during the build. You should accept this as the answer.